# Is there something as 'virtual' numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a question related to proper design of my program and numpy limitations.

I have all data of an entity in one numpy array. The data consist of a sequence of columns (so it is 2D array) and each of these columns has its own logical identity.

I would like to have an object that represents a column of that array. It will have its name and other metadata but most impotantly from the object must be accesible the corresponding column in mentioned array for modifications.

Easy way is to copy the column, modify it and then copy the column back. But obviously that is too much copying.

Is there a way how to create something as a virtual numpy array? What I mean is something that would act as self-contained object but it would in fact be virtual. All read/write operations would be actually performed on the original column in the one array. Therefore no copying would be needed.

If it is not possible with numpy, is it possible with e.g. pandas or something similar?

I will be happy for any suggestions or comments. Maybe it is not in fact even reasonable design and I am open to discussion.

Thank you.

----- Edit:

Thanks for your answers.

I see a lot of confusion with my problem so I will try to explain it with an example.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]])
>>> b = a[:,2]
>>> b[2] += 100
>>> a
array([[  1,   2],
       [  3,   4],
       [  5, 106],
       [  7,   8],
       [  9,  10],
       [ 11,  12]])
>>> a[1,1] += 100
>>> b
array([  2, 104, 106,   8,  10,  12])
# Honestly, I did not know that this works. Thanks to Bobby Ocean whose answer point me to this
# I thought that assigning a column of a to b will copy the column and a, b will not be connected in any way

# But still there is an obvious problem
>>> c = np.array([9,9,9,9,9,9])
>>> b = c
>>> a
array([[  1,   2],
       [  3,   4],
       [  5, 106],
       [  7,   8],
       [  9,  10],
       [ 11,  12]])
# But I believe that this can be solved by property on the object that will represent the whole column.
```

I hoped that I can obtain something as `b` in this example. A column which modifications are executed directly on the "storage" array `a`. This column `b` will be a field in an object that will represent the column.

I did call `b` *virtual* because it has no data, it just points to array `a` (please correct me if I am wrong).

In fact, these columns are time series and they are gathered together in `a` because I believe that most operations will be executed with the whole set of these time series. But also I would like to enable access to just one time serie (one column) in form of self-containing object (it will have its own identifier etc.). From this requirement arise the necessity of *virtual* array `b` that will be a field in this object.

I think that the nice property of np arrays that is showed in the code snippet will satisfy my need. I only need to protect the field against reassigning and I think that this can be easily solved by making this field a property.

Comment: What are you doing across columns?  It's not clear to me why this has to be a 2d array, as opposed to, say, a number independent 1d arrays.  But, yes, there is a form of 'viritual' array, it's called a `view`.  For that you need to go back and read some basic numpy documentation.

Comment: Ok, the views probably will do the trick. Thank you.

The reason to keep the columns in one array is that I expect that it is convinient for the main usecase. But I would like to allow this other way to access the data.

Comment: Edited my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure completely understand your question but if you want to reach specific part of array and make some processes you can break into parts array and come together again. In numpy you can break into parts using `split` function,

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]])

newarr = np.array_split(arr, 3)

print(newarr)
```

and come together like using `concatenate` function as,

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

arr2 = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])

arr = np.concatenate((arr1, arr2), axis=1)

print(arr)
```

Split function tutorials: https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy_array_split.asp

Join function tutorials: https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy_array_join.asp

Comment: I am afraid that these methods will create new arrays, that is something I don't want to do. The goal is to modify the values in the one original array but it should appear as you modify just one dimensional array (the desired column).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean. In general, most numpy operations don't copy anything. Numpy has highly optimized C operations that are generally done in place. For example,

```
import numpy as np

A       = np.arange(20)
A      += 1             #No copying, all in place, highly optimized. 
A[0:3]  = [5,5,5]       #In-place overwriting. 
A.shape = (4,5)         #Just changes the view (what we see) no operations. 
A[:,0]  = A[:,1]+1      #Accesses second column adds 1 and overwrites first column. 
                        #All in place, no copying of the data.
```

Something like pandas is built on numpy and has the same abilities. You can even check id(A) during these steps and see that it is written to the same place in memory still.

Still not sure if you are using the word "virtual" correctly here. The tensorflow module overs truly virtual arrays, which don't have values until you specify them; hence operations can be performed purely algebraically without using any memory for data.

EDIT:

I think you are misunderstanding. Writing "b = [1,2,3,4]" is completely different than writing "b[0] = 6". "b = [1,2,3,4]" says to make the NEW memory object of the thing on the right, [1,2,3,4] and save to the variable "b" (if "b" already existed it is essentially deleted). When you write "b[0] = 5" you are saying to ACCESS the variable "b" with "b"'s access function (which can be different per python class, like numpy having efficient access for example); python then ASSIGNS based on that ACCESS. The way the memory is managed or the access is used and the assignment is done is dependent on the class type. Numpy is very efficient; whereas regularly built-in python lists might not be and might create/copy data is memory while performing operations.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3]
b = a
```

b was overwritten and was assigned the same memory object that a is.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3]
b[0] = a[2]
```

b was ACCESSed at point 0 for a LIST object and does python's "list access assigning action". That action is to find a[2] which is also an access statement, and assign the value, to the already created object of "b".

In your example, if you want to overwrite the objects in "b" and not DELETE "b", then you have to tell numpy to access the whole array.

```
c    = np.array([9,9,9,9,9,9])
b[:] = c
```

[:] I accessed the original "b".

Comment: Actually, numpy often creates new arrays, so `a + b + c` will create a new array, `(a + b)` and finally, `(a + b) + c)` which is why libraries like `numexpr` exist, which allow you to do this sort of thing without creating intermediate arrays fully in memory, but rather, a small, constant overhead

Comment: Those only create new arrays if you didn't assign then to the original array. For example, a += b, updates a, it doesn't create the new array in memory and then overwrite a. Likewise, c = a + b, will clearly make a NEW array, because you told python to make a new object.

Comment: You can test memory addresses and see that the original memory address was overwritten instead of a new class being spawned. For example, print(id(a)); a+=b; print(id(a)).

Comment: No, *assignment* is irrelevant. However, augmented assignment operators do work in-place. So `a = a + b` does create a new array, but `a += b` does not. In any case, my point was that numpy does often create new arrays... Again, it's the entire reason why people have creates libraries like `numexpr`

Comment: Note also using object identity isn't a reliable way to know what is going on with the underlying buffer. For example, the fact that `a += b` does not create a new object doesn't mean that underneath the hood an intermediate array isn't created. Similarly, slicing an array `arr[:n]` creates a new *array object* that shares the underlying buffer with the original object

Comment: Many of your statements are not true. Accessing an array with A[SLICE] returns a numpy VIEW, which behaves differently depending on how it is used. If it is assigned a new variable it is then copied, if it is used in an assigned operation it is cast pointwise and no new memory is created. Likewise, again if you write "a = a + b", this tells python (nothing to do with numpy) to make the new variable "a" and assign it the value of "a + b". "a" original use is deleted. YOU TOLD python to delete "a", this has nothing to do with numpy, clearly numpy has to remake the array for you.

Comment: **no absolutely not** the creation of a view happens regardless of whether you assign to a variable or not . Whether `a` is deleted in that second example *depends on whether or not that object is still being referenced somewhere else*. Note, *a new array object that shares the same underlying buffer* is **exactly** what a view is. I don't know the details of how `ndarray.__iadd__` is implemented, it doesn't create a new object but that's no guarantee that it doesn't use an intermediate array underneath the hood. You can't tell that by using `id`

Comment: id() is most certainly a way to determine memory management, id() returns the "memory address". If you are suggesting that python's kernel rewrites a class objects memory address arbitrarily, then that is a massive security flaw. Testing if an object has the same pointer before and after a set of commands, verifies that python did "in place" operations (maybe those are written efficiently), but that is what it did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213580/discussion-between-bobby-ocean-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Comment: `a += 1` does create a new temporary buffer.  To get an unbuffered version use `ufunc.at` (read its docs).  Trying to micromanage numpy's buffer use is an advanced topic.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, this is what I've been trying to say, that regardless of whether something works in-place, you cannot conclude that it doesn't create a temporary buffer. Is this documented somewhere, though, for `ndarray.__iadd__`?

Comment: And interesting thing is that while `np.add.at` avoids the buffering that `+=` does (`add.at` is the only place I've seen this documented), it does not make the calculation faster.  It just handles some duplicate indexing cases differently.